# Disable magic switch to Apple watch

Tags: apple-watch, siri, airpods, watchos, continuity

I have had a mt Apple watches for 4 years now (first a series 2 now a series 4) and I always have the following issue: When I active Siri on the watch with my AirPods connected to iPhone (and listening to audio) the following happens:

1. Siri is activated on the watch
2. AirPods connect to the watch causing audio playback to stop
3. Siri waits for the AirPods to connect (taks around 3-5 seconds, sometimes longer)
4. Siri is ready for input
5. After input the AirPods don't switch back to the iPhone causing met to take my phone and connect/play again

Is there any way to disable 'Magic Audio Handoff' to the watch? I tried disabling handoff all together in General but this does not seem to stop de AirPods from jumping over.

Answer (score 1):

Try unpairing the AirPods from the watch.  To do this, on the watch go to settings -> Bluetooth click the "i" next to the AirPods and click unpair.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible. The AirPod's are linked using iCloud. When I try to unlink them I get the message:

`Removing this device will remove it from all your devices on your iCloud account`