# How to stop AirPods Pro from switching to Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, airpods

It annoys me that whenever I am listening to music on my iPhone and I want to activate Siri on my Apple Watch (to set a timer or reminder, for example), it takes several seconds for the watch to connect to the AirPods to listen to the input. Additionally, afterwards, music playback does not resume. This circumvents the whole point of the switching and just adds annoying friction.

I have disabled automatic device switching on all my devices, except for Apple Watch, for which I cannot seem to find instructions. Possibly this can’t be done.

When I’m using any other Bluetooth headphones with my iPhone, this does not occur.

Is there any way to stop AirPods from automatically switching to Apple Watch?

Please note that I am NOT looking for instructions to disable switching between other iOS or macOS devices, as I have already disabled that. I am also aware of [Disable magic switch to Apple watch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406781/disable-magic-switch-to-apple-watch) which is not a solution.

Comment: Is a solution like hold the button the watch to engage Siri instantly on the table?

Comment: Indeed. However, if I understand you correctly, this is what I have enabled already and did not mention until now: press-and-hold the Digital Crown to enable Siri. This incurs the delay and failure to resume playing as well.

Comment: Yes - I was trying to see if I even understood what you were seeing. Until the last month, I was delighted with how multiple devices juggled AirPods. Right now, it’s frustrating and janky when you have a paired connection transfer

Comment: Same here. Initially, it seemed like a useful feature to have. However, the more you actually use it, the more it frustrates – and the Apple Watch integration/switch is just sloppy. Sometimes I have to disable Bluetooth on my iPhone to get my Apple Watch to even connect to the AirPods at all, constantly timing out. Once I disable BT on iPhone, they connect instantly. Feels like it’s never been thoroughly tested outside Apple’s campus before releasing it. Every other BT headphones: activate pairing, connect, done.

Comment: Oh it was rock solid for me until iOS 14 this fall. One of the dot updates on one device ruined my Bluetooth bliss.... (or it’s just coincidental and my pairing records are all messed up in some opaque manner I can’t detect)

Comment: Why aren't you just using Siri on your iPhone (either using "hey Siri" or holding the power button on the phone) or listening to music on your Apple Watch?

Comment: @JBallin: Because the whole point of an Apple Watch is mobility – and everything works as expected with any other pair of BT headphones. When my iPhone charges in a different room this would be even more annoying than the delay. Also, audio on an iPhone can come from arbitrary sources. On Apple Watch, it cannot.

Comment: I’m assuming you’re referring to Bluetooth headphones that can connect to more than 1 device at once, which the AirPods cannot. Why not use hey Siri though?

Comment: Still an issue in 2022 :(

Comment: Still causing friction for me on a daily basis as of May 2022 ( this year it’s addressed)

Comment: As a current temporary workaround, using another type of non AirPods Bluetooth headset means this issue doesn’t occur and the watch can be used with Siri without delay. Otherwise I’m always thinking whether or not I can just use the IPhone for the request if I have AirPods on (invoking with hey Siri or button only on iPhone) instead of the watch.