# How to make Siri on AppleWatch not connect to my AirPods and not interrupt my music playing?

Tags: iphone, music, apple-watch, siri, airpods

Who didn't get it from title, here's my case:

I often setup timers and add items to my reminder list using Siri on my AppleWatch. But I also often listen to music (from AirPods, using my iPhone). But each time I use Siri on my AppleWatch, - it interrupts my music to handle the request using AirPods mic... Instead of using built-in AppleWatch mic :\

When timer initiates vibrations, - it also stops music :\

I haven't found anything related in settings. Is it possible to overcome these interrupts? I don't like my music being interrupted.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/410100/151404

Comment: @JBallin I'm not even listening to music with my AppleWatch. I actually use iPhone for that. Though I like that iPhone is paired to AppleWatch so I can change soundtracks right off my ApplyWatch too, even if my my iPhone is somewhere else in the room. I just don't like that it gets interrupted on Siri commands :\